# class changes on mouseover but no effect

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I am trying to create a dropdown menu with JS and scss, I can see that the class does change in my dev console but theres no effect

here is the SCSS

```
    a{
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    background-color: rgba(241, 235, 235, 0.62);
    display: inline-block;

    .expanded{
      height: 20em;
      transition: 0.5s ease;
    }
  }
```

JS

```
 for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    a[i].onmouseover = function(){
      this.classList = "expanded";
    }
    a[i].onmouseleave = function(){
      this.classList.remove("expanded")
    }
  }
```

Comment: Do you mean `this.classList.add("expanded");`

Comment: that doesnt work either, I want to override the a tags ordinary height with expanded

Comment: You are going to almost certainly want to incorporate @Rayon 's suggestion even if it did not fix the sass issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the "&":

```
a{
  &.expanded{
  }
}
```